# Questions on MySQL database replication - different binary log coordinate after READ LOCK

Tags: mysql, locking, replication

I am about to replicate a production database with frequent read/write. Following the instructions on MySQL manual page, I execute the following commands

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> show master status;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000061 | 717697391 |              |                  |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then start my backing up procedure by executing the following commands

```
shell> mysqldump --lock-all-table --databases first second third -u root -p > dbdump.sql
```

I then run the following command

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000061 | 717697462 |              |                  |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show master status;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000061 | 717697462 |              |                  |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the tables are already locked after executing the "READ LOCK" statement, why the coordinate positions are different in two consecutive "show master status" commands? Which position value should I use for my replication?

By the way, do I need to run

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

after the backing up process? or the tables will be automatically unlocked when mysqldump is finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mysqldump` with the `--lock-all-tables` option, `mysqldump` will send `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` at the beginning of the dump, so you don't need to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the question still remains: which binary log coordinate position should I use? Thanks.